# Setting custom value as label in bar highchart (Rshiny)

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny

I have a dataframe with several columns. I draw a bar plot with the values of one of the columns (Ex Count) and I would like to show a label which is not the value of the 'Count' column but the value of the 'Rank' column.
I do not know how to replace the 'point.y' in the dataLabels.

Here is a reproducible example :

```
library("shiny")
library("highcharter")

data <- data.frame(Name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),Count=c(38,44,23,29,26), Rank=10:14)

ui <- fluidPage(
fluidRow(
    column(width = 8,
           highchartOutput("hcontainer",height = "500px")
    )
)
)

server <- function(input, output) {

output$hcontainer <- renderHighchart({
    chart <-  highchart() %>% 
        hc_chart(type = "bar") %>% 
        hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Count"))

    chart <- chart %>% 
        hc_add_series(name="",data = data$Count, dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format='{point.y}'))

    return(chart)
})
} 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks a lot
Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sam,

The easiest way is use `hchart` function.

```
hchart(data, "bar", hcaes(x = Name, y = Count),
       dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format='{point.Rank}'))
```

[image]

This send **all** the data to the highchart object so you can extract the info of each point/row (in highcharts /R language)  via `point.Rank`.

The other way is:

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Count")) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = data$Name) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = data, type = "bar", hcaes(x = Name, y = Count),
                dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format='{point.Rank}'))
```

Here you send **all** the data again: `hc_add_series(data = data, ...)` and not only the count values as you did. When you use `hc_add_series` function with data frames (is a generic function!) you need to use `hcaes(x = Name, y = Count)` in the mapping argument to specify how to use each variable in the chart.

Comment: Wonderful ! Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome. Remember you can _accept_ the answer to help the rest of the community to find answers quicker

Comment: In the answer, near the count vote there is a check symbol: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work